# Predicate in Repository?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA Repository.

```
public interface XXXTransactionRepository extends AbstractRepository<XXXTransaction> {
    public List<XXXTransaction> findByUserId(Long id);
}
```

Can I pass predicate in Repository methods like this?

```
public List<XXXTransaction> findAll(Predicate predicate);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can use the AbstractRepository.fineOne(Specification spec) in which you can pass a Specification.
Here's a sample usage:

```
    xxxTransactionRepository.findOne(new Specificaiton<XXXTransaction>(){

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<XXXTransaction> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder cb) {
                return cb.equal(root.get("fieldName",someVar);
            }
    });
```

You can read more about Specifications at http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-four-jpa-criteria-queries/